# Error in process.bat step FileNotfoundException

Tags: apex, commandline

I am following [Dataloader Command Prompt](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dataLoader.meta/dataLoader/command_line_import_data.htm). I have completed all earlier steps but facing some errors in process.bat part

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\DLTest\process.xml\process-conf.xml

My process.bat path has only below path - but error has some added "process-conf.xml"

> C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\bin>process.bat "C:\DLTest\process.xml" import

[image]

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.. Instead of giving the path fully, I just need to give the directory and Command prompt takes "process-conf.xml" automatically. Also, I had to change the name to "process-conf" from "process" - Below is the path which worked for me.

> C:\DLTest